# pages.forEach() is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am trying to display a list of items from a mongodb database in a Node.js application. I am using ejs as a templating engine. I am encountering the following error on the page:

[image]

**Code for router:**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Get page model
var Page = require('../models/page');

// GET page index
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Page.findOne({}).sort({sorting: 1}).exec(function(err, pages) {
        res.render('admin/pages', {
            pages: pages
        });
    });
});
```

**EJS code:**

```
<%- include('../_layouts/adminheader') %>

<h2 class="page-title">Pages</h2>
<a href="/admin/pages/add-page" class="btn btn-primary">Add a new page</a>
<br><br>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% pages.forEach(function(page) { %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= page.title %></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/pages/edit-page/<%= page.slug %>">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="/admin/pages/edit-page/<%= page._id %>">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        <% }); %>
    </tbody>
</table>

<%- include('../_layouts/adminfooter') %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace .[findOne()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findone_findOne) by [.find()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find), `.findOne()` only return one `page` object, whereas `.find()` return an array of objects:

```
Page.find({}).sort({sorting: 1}).exec(function(err, pages) {
    res.render('admin/pages', {
        pages: pages
    });
});
```